# Change to change iframe source dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm tried to simply change the iframe src at "run time" but it isn't worked for me.

What I'm tried:

```
<html>
<script>
   document.getElementById("test")..contentWindow.document.location.href = "www.google.com";
</script>
<body>

<iframe id="test" src="https://www.w3schools.com">
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

But it isn't change the source,
What is the reason for that?

Thanks!

Comment: code present in script tag is getting executed well before DOM is ready. Try executing the code in onload event callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is as your script tag is getting executed before the DOM loading; your `document.getElementById("test")` code returns nothing. You may use `<body onload="myfunction()">` and write your required code in it so that it will get executed after the DOM loaded or you may try below jQuery apporach:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  
  $("#test").attr("src","http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42504395/change-to-change-iframe-source-dynamically");
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="test" src="https://www.w3schools.com">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly if using plain JS you need to run the script later on, as it will be hitting too early (before DOM ready-state).

Secondly, you can just set `.src = url`.

You can even use the `jQuery` method `$(document).ready()` combined with its selectors.

```html
<html>
<body>

<iframe id="test" src="https://www.w3schools.com">
</iframe>
</body>
<script>
   document.getElementById("test").src = "http://www.bing.com";
</script>
</html>
```

jQuery version:

```html
<html>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#test').attr('src','http://www.bing.com');
   });
</script>
<body>

<iframe id="test" src="https://www.w3schools.com">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
 document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("src",Path);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("src","www.google.com");

$(#test).attr('src','www.google.com');
```