# How do i dynamically load content into an iframe

Tags: javascript

I have some code that should dynamically load an iframe. The issue is i have a function that should make it cascade to the next id appended to the iframe. I need someone to help pinpont the issue with my code.

```js
const $iframe = $("#content-frame");
$($iframe).attr('src', cath);

var cath = 'https://exanple.com' + myIds[i] + '/embed/dynamic?';
console.log(cath);
const myIds = ['1_aq4jiqb', '1_4u0ocu4u'];

function switchId() {
  for (let i = 0; i < myIds.length; i++) {
    cath = 'https://www.exanple.com' + myIds[i] + '/embed/dynamic?';

  }
}
setInterval(function() {
  switchId()
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<iframe id="content-frame" src="" width="400px" height="400px"></iframe>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change to change iframe source dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42504395/change-to-change-iframe-source-dynamically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This overwrites cath over and over again `cath = 'https://www.exanple.com' + myIds[i] + '/embed/dynamic?';` and you are not using cath anywhere.

You do NOT want any other loop than what you get with setInterval

Also no need to cast a jQuery object to a jQuery object.

I wrap the list

```js
const $iframe = $("#content-frame");
const myIds = ['1_aq4jiqb', '1_4u0ocu4u'];
let cnt = 0;
$iframe.on("load",function() { console.log($(this).attr("src"))})

setInterval(() => {
  const url = 'https://www.example.com/' + myIds[cnt] + '/embed/dynamic?';
  $iframe.attr('src', url);
  cnt++;
  if (cnt >= myIds.length) cnt = 0; // wrap the list
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<iframe id="content-frame" src="" width="400px" height="400px"></iframe>
```

Same code without jQuery

```js
const iframe = document.getElementById("content-frame");
const myIds = ['1_aq4jiqb', '1_4u0ocu4u'];
let cnt = 0;
iframe.addEventListener("load",e => console.log(e.target.src))

setInterval(() => {
  const url = 'https://www.example.com/' + myIds[cnt] + '/embed/dynamic?';
  iframe.src = url;
  cnt++;
  if (cnt >= myIds.length) cnt = 0; // wrap the list
}, 3000);
```

```html
<iframe id="content-frame" src="" width="400px" height="400px"></iframe>
```

Comment: do i need  myIds[cnt % 2], there will be more than 2 items in array

Comment: how would i detect everytime a iframe src has been loaded? i want to trigger an alert

Comment: $iframe.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
            console.log('content has been loaded!');
        });  but i would need this for each src?

Comment: its only 1 iframe

Comment: See updated scripts. You only need an event handler for the iframe.

Comment: Also note you cannot use `this` or `$(this)` if you use an arrow function

Comment: is there a way to time it so that after the item loads there is a brief pause? I think right now it skips some, for instance i extended the time to 15000 and seems some get skipped here and there

Comment: We can use the load even and a timeout instead of interval

Answer (score 0):

Only change iframe element `SRC` to solve the issue.

```
    const myIds = ['1_aq4jiqb', '1_4u0ocu4u'];
    let cnt = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
       const src = 'https://www.example.com/' + myIds[cnt] + '/embed/dynamic?';
       document.getElementById('myIframe').src = src;
       cnt++;
       if (cnt >= myIds.length) cnt = 0; 
    }, 3000);
```